# Citation of Imam suyuti in Qu'ran 39:3?

Tags: quran, tafseer, sahaba

I was reading Imam Suyuti's Tafsir in surah 39:3 and I came across this narration of Ibn Abbas

"وأخْرَجَ جُوَيْبِرٌ عَنِ ابْنِ عَبّاسٍ في قَوْلِهِ: ﴿والَّذِينَ اتَّخَذُوا مِن دُونِهِ أوْلِياءَ﴾ قالَ: أُنْزِلَتْ في ثَلاثَةِ أحْياءٍ، عامِرٍ وكِنانَةَ وبَنِي سَلِمَةَ، كانُوا يَعْبُدُونَ الأوْثانَ ويَقُولُونَ: المَلائِكَةُ بَناتُهُ، فَقالُوا: إنَّما نَعْبُدُهم لِيُقَرِّبُونا إلى اللَّهِ زُلْفى"

I could not find This Narration anywhere so i was wondering if it is the Quotation legit?

Comment: It is very likely that this narration is dai'f or even fabricated. Juwaybir ibn Sai'd al-Azdi جويبر بن سعيد الأزدي is known as a mufassir, but his reputation as a hadith narrator is bad.